# Vim regex removing spaces before the end of line

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file, that contains spaces at the end of the line and they should be removed.

When I use the following command:

```
%s/\s+$//
```

Vim shows me an error that pattern is not found. What is wrong here?

**NOTE:** actually, I can use the `%s/\s*$//` command but I want to understand the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Vim shows me an error that pattern is not found

You need to **escape** the quantifier `+`.

```
:%s/\s\+$//g
```

You might also want to refer to [**Quantifiers, Greedy and Non-Greedy**](http://vimregex.com/#Non-Greedy).

Comment: Actually `g` flag isn't needed since there can be only one `\s\+$` per line.

Comment: If you want to get no warning nor interruptions of macro if there was no spaces anywhere at ends of lines, replace `//` by `//e`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
%s/ \+$//
```

OR:

```
%s/\s\+$//
```

As `+` needs to be escaped in vim regex.

Comment: `+` needs to be escaped only in `vim`?

Comment: @Alex: In sed also `+` needs to be escaped unless being used in extended regex mode.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ["very magic"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) mode with `\v`, you only need to escape alphanumeric specials:

> `%s:\v\s+%(//.*)?$::`

(Here `:` is used as a separator, instead of `/`. You can use almost any non-alphanumeric ASCII character.)

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it:

```
:%s/  *$//g
```

if you do not want to input '\' chars ;)